# How does ops update zookeeper (in a shared configuration scenario)?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

So far I haven't seen a good way of updating zookeeper. I am thinking of writing a web browser for zookeeper. Even then, the hierarchical key-value might not be intuitive. Another idea is for ops to update a MySQL table and then run a script to update Zookeeper which in turn notifies all the apps. Thoughts? What are the best practices?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by updating? Are you updating zookeeper data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an eclipse plugin that lets you do read/write operations. Coming in 3.4 is a Hue based web frontend to zookeeper. There is of course the zkCli command line tool that comes with the zk distribution.

1. http://www.massedynamic.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Eclipse_Plug-in_for_ZooKeeper
2. http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/GSoCMonitoringAndWebInterface

The eclipse plugin is a little slow, but works quite well. The web app is faster, but has a dependency on the REST interface in 3.4

update: Exhibitor from Netflix also provides a reasonable GUI along with other pretty cool capabilities of managing a zookeeper ensemble.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of GUIs available that allow to create/edit/delete the nodes. I have personally tried 
[node-zk-browser](https://github.com/killme2008/node-zk-browser) and [zk-web](https://github.com/qiuxiafei/zk-web) and would recommend zk-web